# PHP: Dynamic image grid with different widths

Tags: php, image, dynamic, grid, gallery

On my site I have multiple images with the same height but with three different widths. And I want to display these in a nice grid. When an image is uploaded I check if the image should be wide or tall.

I then have three different sizes for images
s, m & l

s for tall images and m & l for wide images.

These images are displayed in a table where a small (s) image takes up 1 spot, medium (m) takes up 2 spots and large (l) takes up 3 spots. And there are 3 spots per row.

If I have maybe 8 images (4 tall and 4 wide) I want it to look like this (w = white-space):

```
sss
ms
l
l
l
```

instead of

```
sss
sww
l
l
l
l
```

This means that the first 3 images are just small images. And since I need a medium image for the second row then I strech one of the wide images to take up 2 spots. Then there is a tall image beside that one and the last three rows are just three wide images, one on each row.

I hope I explained this well enough.

EDIT:

Or let's say I've got 4 images 2 tall and 2 wide (**w = white-space**):

Instead of displaying it like this

```
ssw
l
l
```

I want it to look like this:

```
sm (or ms)
sm (or ms)
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: My question is, how do I make it dynamically order my images like I showed with 8 images instead of just having first 4 tall images and then 4 wide images with white-space everywhere?

Comment: If you had 2 s` and 2 l`, you're going to have whitespace regardless...

Comment: Nope, if there are 2 wide & 2 tall images, the wide images scale to 2 m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several libraries for this, the easiest is [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

You could achieve what you want with minimal code because it's only variable widths rather than variable widths and heights, but might as well use a library that already handles this rather than spend the time yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Though I did end up using [Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin)

Comment: it doesn't look like wookmark handles horizontal alignment, but I might be wrong.